# Error al hacer bundle en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Esto es lo que me arroja la consola:

```
    The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 5.0.2)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.2)

    spree (~> 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
      spree_frontend (= 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
        canonical-rails (~> 0.0.4) was resolved to 0.0.11, which depends on
          rails (< 5.0, >= 3.1)

    spree (~> 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
        deface (~> 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
          rails (>= 3.1)

    spree (~> 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.0.rc1) was resolved to 3.1.0.rc1, which depends on
        rails (~> 4.2.6)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes aplicar `bundle update` para ver si resuelve tu problema o bajar tu version de rails en tu GEMFILE  a `gem 'rails', '4.2.6'`

Answer (score 0):

Debes actualizar spree a una versión que sea compatible con rails 5.
Estás usando spree 3.1.0.rc1, sin embargo según las indicaciones [en el github de la gema](https://github.com/spree/spree#rails-5), debes usar:

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
```